# how to make vertical resizable panel with background image (the problems with zoom in chrome)

Tags: html, css, background-image, panel, resizable

I want to make a panel with background image, which can be resized vertically. So the simple idea is to split actual image in three parts: header, body-repeat-part, footer. It looks something like this

```
<tr><td><div class='header'></div></td></tr>
<tr><td><div class='body'>whatever goes here</div></td></tr>
<tr><td><div class='footer'></div></td></tr>

.header {background:url(header.png); width:110px; height:20px;}
.footer {background:url(footer.png); width:110px; height:40px;}
.body {background:url(body-repeat.png); repeat-y; width:110px;}
```

So I slice my image which is 100x100 into three parts - header.png - 100x20, footer.png - 100x40, and body-repeat.png - 100x1

Everything works fine in Ie9 and firefox. And even chrome works fine with 100% zoom. However when I change zoom in Chrome the picture becomes jagged i.e. you could see it's "glued" from 3 parts. Apparently chrome scales differently these images.

So my question is - could this be fixed somehow? Or is there any way to make resizable panel with background image?

Many thanks for the replies.

Comment: Are you using a table for layout?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to force no paddings, borders and margins on that tables and divs, and then try to add the CSS3 background size property!

```
.header {
background-image:url(header.png); 
background-size:110px 20px;
}
```

More about CSS Background size properties: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

It is better too try to avoid tables when making a layout structure :)

**EDIT:**
You can try too to add the

> background-size: cover;

property on the full page background so the background image will fit 100% of the width and height of the given area.

A great and very complete tutorial about background-size: http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/